# 10-digit number with leading digit higher than 1 throws an "out of range" error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I'm working with some points in ArcMap 10.3 that have specified volumes, and I am plotting them so that the points have graduated symbols. Nothing particularly strenuous.

However, I noticed one of my largest observations, at just over 2,200,000,000, was nullified in the table.

When I went to change it from  to the correct input, it gave me the "the value you have entered is out of range or is not a whole number" error.

I can put in 2 billion, but not anything higher than that.

I don't know if this is related to the fact that the field type is currently set at "Long" or not, but I am trying to find the root of the issue.

Normally I would just exclude the point, but since it's one of the largest it really should be represented on the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very conveniently, the max value of a LONG field is limited to 2,147,483,647....   just beneath your max value of 2,200,000,000! :)

You'll have to update the field type or adjust all your values by a certain modifier.

You should be using a float or double field type for large values.

Source: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/ArcGIS_field_data_types/005s0000000p000000/

Comment: You're kidding. I figured it was type-related; what should I change the type to so that it's accepted?

Comment: Float would be what you need (double would work too, but overkill).

Comment: To clarify, double is overkill if your value contains less than eight significant digits.